# How to commit received data to Vue store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to:

- get element's data `@click` using `getDetails` method and put it into `fileProperties: []`
- and then send that data to store using `fileDetails` computed property

This worked for my other components which have `v-model` and simple true/false state, but I'm not sure how to send the created by the method array of data to the store properly.

In other words, how do I make this computed property to get the data from `fileProperties: []` and commit it to store? The `fileDetails` computed property below is not committing anything.

### Code:

```html
  [...]

  <div @click="getDetails(file)"></div>

  [...]


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'files',
    data () {
      return {
        fileProperties: []
      }
    },
    props: {
      file: Object
    },
    methods: {
      getDetails (value) {
        this.fileProperties = [{"extension": path.extname(value.path)}, 
                              {"size": this.$options.filters.prettySize(value.stat.size)}]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      isFile () {
        return this.file.stat.isFile()
      },
      fileDetails: {
        get () {
          return this.$store.state.Settings.fileDetails
        },
        set (value) {
          this.$store.commit('loadFileDetails', this.fileProperties)
        }     
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

### store module:

```html
const state = {
    fileDetails: []
}

const mutations = {
    loadFileDetails (state, fileDetails) {
        state.fileDetails = fileDetails
    }
}
```

### Example on codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxjdNo?editors=1011

In this codepen example, how can I send over the dummy data `[ { "1": 1 }, { "2": 2 } ]` to the store on button click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are never setting the value for `fileDetails`, so the `set` method of the computed property is never getting called. [Here's the documentation on computed setters.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

If the `fileProperties` data is really just the same as the `fileDetails` data, then get rid of it and set `fileDetails` directly in your `getDetails` method.

---

Here's a working example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fileDetails: null
  },
  mutations: {
    loadFileDetails (state, fileDetails) {
      state.fileDetails = fileDetails
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      fileProperties: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDetails (value) {
      this.fileDetails = [{"1": 1}, {"2": 2}]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fileDetails: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.fileDetails
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('loadFileDetails', value)
      }     
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>element data:</h1>
  {{fileDetails}}

  <hr>

  <h1>store data:</h1>
  <p>(should display the same data on button click)</p>
  {{fileDetails}}

  <hr>

  <button @click="getDetails">btn</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much for the explanation and the working example! People like you make stackoverflow a great place for newbies to learn, thank you for that!